# Displaying headers and footers in a PDF generated by Rotativa

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, pdf-generation, rotativa

I'm trying to specify headers and footers in a PDF generated by Rotativa library. As the author answered [here](https://github.com/webgio/Rotativa/issues/13) it should be possible using CSS (described [here](http://www.princexml.com/doc/7.1/page-headers-footers/)). However, I'm not able to do this.

I have a stylesheet loaded in the meta tag:

```
<link href="print.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print" />
```

And in the stylesheet at the bottom:

```
@page {
    @top-left {
        content: "TOP SECRET";
        color: red
    }
    @bottom-right {
        content: counter(page);
        font-style: italic
    }
}
```

And then generating PDF by:

```cs
public ActionResult ShowPdf()
{
     var model = new Model();
     return new ViewAsPdf("view.cshtml", model)
                {
                    FileName = "Report.pdf",
                    CustomSwitches = "--print-media-type"
                };
}
```

And then nothing appears in the header and footer of the PDF. Any ideas?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I've found a [documentation of wkhtmltopdf](https://wkhtmltopdf.org/usage/wkhtmltopdf.txt) (or a better [archived version](http://web.archive.org/web/20130318095015/https://madalgo.au.dk/%7Ejakobt/wkhtmltoxdoc/wkhtmltopdf-0.9.9-doc.html)) and it is described there how to manage headers and footers.

Basically you can just add `--header-center "text"` (or similar switches) to the argument list and that's all.

So using it with Rotativa it would be:

```cs
public ActionResult ShowPdf()
{
     var model = new Model();
     return new ViewAsPdf("view.cshtml", model)
                {
                    FileName = "Report.pdf",
                    CustomSwitches = "--print-media-type --header-center \"text\""
                };
}
```

(I don't know if `--print-media-type` is necessary.)

Comment: Just tested and you don't need the `--print-media-type`

Answer (score 9):

If you wanted to display a View instead of text in the header/footer then you can do so like this:

```
public ActionResult ViewPDF()
{
      string customSwitches = string.Format("--print-media-type --allow {0} --footer-html {0} --footer-spacing -10",
                Url.Action("Footer", "Document", new { area = ""}, "https"));


     return new ViewAsPdf("MyPDF.cshtml", model)
                {
                    FileName = "MyPDF.pdf",
                    CustomSwitches = customSwitches
                };
}

[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult Footer()
{
    return View();
}
```

Don't forget to add the  [AllowAnonymous] attribute on the Footer action otherwise Rotatina can't get access to the path.

Comment: I had to change it to `http` but it works nicely. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: where to put the footer.html in the directory?

Answer (score 5):

Here is how I did it (in full):

```
public ActionResult PrintPDF(int? selectedSiteRotaId, int selectedSiteId)
{
    string footer = "--footer-center \"Printed on: " + DateTime.Now.Date.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") + "  Page: [page]/[toPage]\"" + " --footer-line --footer-font-size \"9\" --footer-spacing 6 --footer-font-name \"calibri light\"";

    return new ActionAsPdf("RenderPDF", new { selectedSiteRotaId = selectedSiteRotaId, selectedSiteId = 7 }) 
    {
        FileName = "PDF_Output.pdf",
        PageOrientation = Orientation.Landscape,
        MinimumFontSize = 10, 
        //PageMargins  = new Margins(5,5,5,5),
        PageSize = Size.A3,
        CustomSwitches = footer
    };

    //var pdfResult = new ActionAsPdf("RenderPDF", new { selectedSiteRotaId = selectedSiteRotaId, selectedSiteId = 7 })
    //{
    //    FileName = "PDF_Output.pdf",
    //    PageOrientation = Orientation.Landscape,
    //    MinimumFontSize = 10
    //};

    //var binary = pdfResult.BuildPdf(this.ControllerContext);

    //return File(binary, "application/pdf");
}


public ActionResult RenderPDF(int? selectedSiteRotaId, int selectedSiteId)
{
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "PrintPDF", new { selectedSiteRotaId = selectedSiteRotaId, selectedSiteId = 7 });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
string customSwitches = string.Format("--header-spacing \"0\" --footer-spacing \"0\"  --footer-html {0}   ", Url.Action("Footer", "Invoice", new { }, "http"));
        return new ViewAsPdf(saleInvoiceVm)
        {
            PageOrientation = Orientation.Portrait,
            PageSize = Rotativa.AspNetCore.Options.Size.A4,
            PageMargins = { Left = 5, Bottom = 25, Right = 7, Top = 10 },
            CustomSwitches = customSwitches,
        };
```

Comment: Please fix your answer by putting all of your code into a code block

Answer (score -2):

try it it will work 100 %

```
 return new ViewAsPdf("MyPDF.cshtml", model)
            {
                FileName = "MyPDF.pdf",
                CustomSwitches = customSwitches
            };
```

}

Comment: Need to define customSwitches pls.