# How to display page breaks in PDF generated by Rotativa

Tags: asp.net-mvc, pdf, rotativa

In my ASP.NET MVC 4 app, I have an index view that has several partial views embedded in it. I installed latest version 1.6.1 of Rotativa via NuGet. Now I can print the index page to a PDF using Rotativa. I would like to have a page break in the PDF after every partial view. How can this be achieved using Rotativa?

I tried to follow [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15250505/displaying-headers-and-footers-in-a-pdf-generated-by-rotativa) to use CustomSwitches but there does not seem to be one for page break. I used [this article](http://letsfollowtheyellowbrickroad.blogspot.com/2012/02/rotativa-how-to-print-pdf-in-aspnet-mvc.html) to generate the PDF

Answer (score 31, accepted):

If you are using 1.6.1 you can just add the page breaks in the CSS (this does not work consistently in 1.5.0, I have not tested 1.6.0)

So add this style, not to a specific element like p.breakhere{...} but as shown below (some folks had issues on a specific element)

```
<STYLE TYPE="text/css">
 .breakhere { page-break-after: always }
</STYLE>
```

Then in your html just do this

```
<P CLASS="breakhere">
```

And it should break nicely. Do be aware that 1.6.1 has a bug with Ghosted images, intermittently...
See this SO entry [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23071227/rotativa-1-6-1-image-ghosting-but-only-on-qa-not-dev-or-integration-server)

Comment: I used the following  `<div id="A" style="page-break-after:always;">@{Html.RenderPartial("View1");}</div>` for each view on the index.cshtml page. You are right that adding p.breakhere(...) would cause the issues as it would probably apply this style to all the paragraphs.

Comment: Nam, only if you apply the breakhere class...my point was that Rotativa (wkhtmltopdf) doesn't handle them correctly unless they are a root style.

Comment: Works for me also inside another css file (so no root style, in case I understand you correctly), but I had to remove the `overflow: auto` from the MVC4 generated CSS section `#main` - no idea what problems an overflow: auto could cause ...

Answer (score 9):

The answer is correct but you have to do it in a different manner like:

```
<div style="page-break-after: always;">Content before page breaks</div>
<div>Content after page breaks<div>
```

This does the trick!

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 4):

You can use any of this three CSS code to set the page break for an element,

```
page-break-after
page-break-before
page-break-inside
```

According to your situation.

Answer (score 2):

This works every time for me and in all browsers. My application is ASP.NET MVC3 Razor.

In your style sheet (.css) or in a style tag put this:

```
@media all {    .page-break { display: none; } }

@media print {  .page-break { display: block; page-break-before: always; } }
```

Where you want your page to break put this:

```
<div class="page-break"></div>
```

Works perfect in all browsers

Answer (score 0):

I found 1.6.1 works locally, but hosted on 2012 R2 windows, a QT 6.2 incompatible version breaks the generation of the application so this was not the solution for me. Instead, i ended up forcing a large margin-top in my css and then that actually forced my content to the top of the next generated page consistently, and therefore achieved my requirement. Strange, but it worked.

```
Qt: Untested Windows version 6.2 detected!
Error: Failed loading page https://a.b.co.uk/c/d/1(sometimes it will work just to ignore this error with --load-error-handling ignore)
```

Added this and it force made my new page for the content i needed it to...

```
<div class="row-fluid page-break" style="margin-top: 800px;">
```

I think a page height in pixels is 824px, so this pushes it over. It's a workaround, but i've just spent a few hours trying to get this to work, and was about to change Rotativa for another solution, but this was a easier option.