# Display dynamic header using Rotativa pdf in MVC net core

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core-mvc, pdf-generation, rotativa

I want to display dynamic header in a cshtml. When i try to pass it using CustomSwitches i get an error like *QPaintDevice: Cannot destroy paint device that is being paintedpure virtual method called terminate called without an active exception*.

Calling Rotativa component(it's in a class library) from mvc Controller to print the dynamic view without header works correctly but not with the header. Is there anyway to solve this problem?

Thank you for your answers.

Edit: Example using Rotativa

string header = $"/Header.cshtml";

var customSwitches = string.Format("--header-html  "{0}" " + "--header-spacing "0" ", header);

```
        var view = new ViewAsPdf(pdfView.ToViewRoute(culture), model: viewModel)
        {
            PageOrientation = option.PageOrientation,
            IsGrayScale = option.IsGrayScale,
            MinimumFontSize = option.MinimumFontSize,
            PageSize = option.PageSize,
            PageMargins = option.PageMargins,
            CustomSwitches = customSwitches
        };
        return view;
```

Comment: Can you share some of the code which call Rotativa component? Because I cannot reproduce the error.

Comment: Thank you, i've just edit the question with an exmaple of how i'm using it. Do you have an example with dynamic header working? Thank you.

Comment: Header refers to the first page of the pdf, or the head of each page in the pdf?

Comment: Thank you for your response. I need the same header in all the pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`customSwitches` may not find /header.cshml. You need to give the correct path.

```
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Pdf()
    {
        string customSwitches = string.Format(" --print-media-type --page-offset 2 --footer-center [page] --allow {0} --footer-html {0} --footer-spacing -180 ",
            Url.Action("header", "home", new { area = "" }, "https"));
        var pageList = new List<tbpage>();
        pageList.Add(new tbpage()
        {
            page_name = "1",
            page_no = "a"
        });
        return new ViewAsPdf("PdfDemo", model: pageList)
            {
                PageOrientation = Rotativa.AspNetCore.Options.Orientation.Portrait,  
                IsGrayScale = true,
                MinimumFontSize = 20,
                 PageSize = Rotativa.AspNetCore.Options.Size.A5,
                 PageMargins = { Left = 20, Bottom = 20, Right = 20, Top = 20 },
                CustomSwitches = customSwitches
        };
    }
```

Model

```
public class tbpage
{
    public string page_name { get; set; }
    public string page_no { get; set; }
}
```

Pdf

[image]

In addition, if it is still incorrect, please add `[AllowAnonymous]` to the action `Header`. You can also refer to [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15250505/displaying-headers-and-footers-in-a-pdf-generated-by-rotativa).

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult Header()
{
    return View();
}
```

Comment: Here is the all code. If you have any other issue, please show more key code.